# Changing CSS Property From an Array using JS

Tags: css, reactjs

I am currently building a todo app, and from react, I am using CSS to custom my todo items' margin!

The problem is, I only needed the first element to have a `margin-top` of `110px`. Here's what it'll look like when I apply it to every item - [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJrLr.png)

It's that the todolist items are too separated!

But if I removed the margin of `110px`, the item is behind the textbox!
[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CU66C.png)

Is there a way to change the property of first item? I can delete the `margin-top: 110px` from the css file, and change the 1st item using JS. My planned function -

```
function addTodo() {
  setList([...list, value]);
  const firstItem = list.findIndex(0);
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using map to render the values? I believe the change will need to be done where you render them

Comment: Please provide a [mre] in the question. You can likely use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/338537) (icon looks like `<>` in the toolbar) to do so.

Answer (score 1):

:first-of-type selector in CSS allows you to target the first occurence of an element within its container. Also, another option might be to select first child of the element, you can use :first-child pseudo-class.

Answer (score 0):

There are several possibilities to solve this problem. I think the simplest one is to just build a container that contains all list items, and set it's `padding-top` or `margin-top` to `110px`. The result could look like this:

```css
.frame {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  text-align: center;
}

.control-button {
  position: absolute;
}

/* this is the container that holds all your items */
.items-container {
  margin-top: 40px; /* in your case, it should be 110px */
}

.item {
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="frame">

      <div class="control-button">
        <u>add item</u>
      </div>

      <!-- this is the important part, the container with the items -->
      <div class="items-container">
        <div class="item">
          This is an item.
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          This is another item.
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I think this solution is the most simple and flexible one. You can easily add left, right or bottom margins too and you don't have to worry about which items it affects.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution you can go with is using the `:nth-child(n)` pseudo class in CSS or `:first-of-type`.

Try this code:

```
.item:nth-child(1) {
  margin-top: 110px;
}
```